# pushing to array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to push an object into an array using mongodb and just can't get it to work. Am I doing something wrong? Would appreciate any help.

```
app.post('/api/savedJobs', (req, res) => { 

        const job =  req.body.data 

        User.findOneAndUpdate({
             _id: req.user._id 
            }, { $push: { savedJobs: job } }
        ) 
        .then((res, err) => err ? console.log(err) : console.log('done'))   

        res.json(req.body.data)
      })
```

This is how my schema looks

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    googleId: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    image: String,
    interests: String,
    activeProjects: String,
    city: String,
    country: String,
    about: String,
    skills: String,
    savedJobs: Array,
    timestamp: ''
})
```

Comment: Does your `req.user._id` contains userId?.... Console it

Comment: Yes it does. console.log(req.user._id) logs out 5a46ce19d1aa08166c6bdbd4. If I don't use $push but just specify the property and the value it updates, but need an array

Comment: Use `$set` instead

Comment: what is your "job" object contain please Log. If its a Array Of Object then u need to add  $each in Push.